# Heroku Master Branch Deploy Rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to push a discord bot and getting this error.It downloads the dependencies and when it comes to installing node modules it shows this error.I had tried everything to resolve still whenever I try to deploy this master branch it keeps on showing me this.Hope I will get a solution soon. :)

```
    -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
    -----> Node.js app detected
           
    -----> Creating runtime environment
           
           NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
           NODE_VERBOSE=false
           NODE_ENV=production
           NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
           
    -----> Installing binaries
           engines.node (package.json):  >=16.x
           engines.npm (package.json):   *
           
           Resolving node version >=16.x...
           Downloading and installing node 18.7.0...
           Bootstrapping npm * (replacing 8.15.0)...
           npm 8.15.1 installed
           
    -----> Installing dependencies
           Installing node modules
           npm ERR! code 1
           npm ERR! path /tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas
           npm ERR! command failed
           npm ERR! command sh /tmp/install-41a5e37c.sh
           npm ERR! Failed to execute '/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.7.0 | linux | x64
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz 
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.3 and node@18.7.0 (node-v108 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz 
           npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
           npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
           npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.7.0 | linux | x64
           npm ERR! gyp info ok 
           npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
           npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
           npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.7.0 | linux | x64
           npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
           npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/node-v18.7.0-headers.tar.gz
           npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/node-v18.7.0-headers.tar.gz
           npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
           npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/app/.cache/node-gyp/18.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/app/.cache/node-gyp/18.7.0',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/app/.cache/node-gyp/18.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
           npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
           npm ERR! Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
           npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
           npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
           npm ERR! No package 'pangocairo' found
           npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.7.0
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
           npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_388194cd/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_388194cd/node_modules/canvas
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.7.0
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
           npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
           
           npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
           npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Digio/_logs/2022-07-28T12_56_09_291Z-debug-0.log
    -----> Build failed
           
           We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
           https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
           
           Some possible problems:
           
           - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
             https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
           
           Love,
           Heroku
           
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
     !     Push failed
```

package.json

```json
{
      "name": "Discord_BotV12",
      "version": "1.0.0", 
      "main": "src/index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node .",
        "generate-docs": "jsdoc --configure C:/Users/benja/Desktop/Discord-Bot/jsdoc.json --verbose",
        "replit": "npm init -y && npm i --save-dev node@16 && npm config set prefix=$(pwd)/node_modules/node && export PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/node/bin:$PATH"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.x",
        "npm": "*"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Spiderjockey02/Discord-Bot/issues"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@vitalets/google-translate-api": "^8.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "canvacord": "^5.2.3",
        "chalk": "^4.1.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dateformat": "^4.6.3",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "discord.js": "^13.0.0",
        "duckduckgo-images-api": "^1.0.5",
        "erela.js": "github:menudocs/erela.js#build",
        "erela.js-deezer": "^1.0.5",
        "erela.js-facebook": "^1.0.2",
        "erela.js-spotify": "^1.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "genius-lyrics-api": "^3.0.6",
        "i18next": "^21.6.10",
        "i18next-node-fs-backend": "^2.1.3",
        "minecraft-server-util": "^5.2.9",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.2.0",
        "optiic": "^0.0.15",
        "puppeteer": "^13.3.0",
        "r6api.js": "^4.0.0",
        "radio-browser": "^2.1.6",
        "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
        "simple-node-logger": "^21.8.12",
        "string-progressbar": "^1.0.3",
        "string-similarity": "^4.0.4",
        "tinyurl": "^1.1.7",
        "urban-dictionary": "^3.0.0",
        "valid-url": "^1.0.9",
        "weather-js": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "clean-jsdoc-theme": "^3.2.7",
        "eslint": "^8.8.0",
        "jsdoc": "^3.5.5"
      },
      "optionalDependencies": {
        "bufferutil": "^4.0.4",
        "erlpack": "github:discord/erlpack",
        "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.6",
        "zlib-sync": "^0.1.7"
      }
}
```

Comment: `Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.` this is your error. You need to install this. This cannot be done with the javascript buildpack alone. Try to install it with the Apt buildpack as well and post the new errors when you are stuck.

Comment: Updated package.json